# Search View is not showing search results

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, filter, searchview

I have been trying to add a search filter in a `RecyclerView` activity. Though the search menu is on the action bar, it does not show the search results. I have given some details of the project bellow:

1. **Manifest**

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
 </intent-filter>`
```

2. **Menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />

</menu>
```

3. **Activity**

`````
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView= (SearchView) searchViewItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);````
`````

4.**Adapter**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    List<ProfileModel> myOfficerslist;
    List<ProfileModel> myOfficerslistfull;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<ProfileModel> myOfficerslist, Activity activity) {
        this.context = context;
        this.myOfficerslist = myOfficerslist;
        this.myOfficerslistfull=new ArrayList<>(myOfficerslist);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_layout, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textName.setText(myOfficerslistfull.get(position).getName());
        holder.textDesignation.setText(myOfficerslistfull.get(position).getDesignation());
        holder.textPosting.setText(myOfficerslistfull.get(position).getPlaceofposting());
        holder.textPhone.setText(myOfficerslistfull.get(position).getCell());
        holder.textEmail.setText(myOfficerslistfull.get(position).getEmail());
        holder.profileimage.setImageResource(myOfficerslistfull.get(position).getProfileImage());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myOfficerslistfull.size();
    }

   @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
   {
        return myFilter;
    }
    Filter myFilter=new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String searchText=constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            List<ProfileModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (searchText.length()==00 || searchText.isEmpty()){
                filteredList.addAll(myOfficerslistfull);
            }
            else
            {
                for (ProfileModel row : myOfficerslistfull) {
                    if (row.getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchText)|| (row.getDesignation().toLowerCase().contains(searchText)
                    ||(row.getPlaceofposting().toLowerCase().contains(searchText)))) {
                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }
                }

            }
            FilterResults filterResults=new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values=filteredList;
            return filterResults;
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            myOfficerslist.clear();
            myOfficerslist.addAll((Collection<? extends ProfileModel>) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            ImageView profileimage;
            TextView textName;
            TextView textDesignation;
            TextView textPosting;
            TextView textPhone;
            TextView textEmail;

            public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

                super(itemView);
                profileimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
                textName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
                textDesignation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDesignation);
                textPosting = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPosting);
                textPhone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPhone);
                textEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textEmail);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors found at first shot:

- In `getItemCount()` You need to return the size of the filtered list not the size of the entire list:

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myOfficerslist.size();
    }
```

- In `onBindViewHolder()` Get the data from the filtered list not from the entire list: So change all the occurrences of `myOfficerslistfull` to `myOfficerslist`
- I guess the double 00 here is a typo, so add only a single 0

```
if (searchText.length()==0 || searchText.isEmpty()){
```

Comment: Thank you very much Zain.  My filtered list is myOfficerslistfull. That's why I used it in the getItemcount() as well as in the onBindViewholder. However changing to the original list i.e. myOfficerslist made it functional. Thanks again

Comment: Glad that could help.. Please accept the answer by hitting top left tick mark